# "Displaying" the line feed or carriage return characters in Assembly language

Tags: assembly, newline, carriage-return, linefeed

Folks I'm trying to figure out how to move to the next line in Assembly. I have tried a few lines of code with little luck. Basically here is what I have:

```
    ; display "F"
    mov     al, "F"
    mov     dl, al
    call    writechar

    ; display the 'h'
    mov al, 68h
    call writechar
```

On the console I end up with "Fh". How can I push "h" to the next line, if I wanted to? Or move to the next line in general?
I tried adding:

```
mov dl, 10
mov dl, 13
```

That didn't work. How do I implement it?

Comment: What's the operating system, what does `writechar` do and did you call `mov dl, 10` and then `writechar` or did you call `mov dl, 10`,  `mov dl, 13` and then `writechar`

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. Writechar is a function that grabs what's in the  AL register and displays on the console.  I called in this order : `mov dl, 10,  mov dl, 13, mov al, 68h,  call writechar` that didnt work. And then switched 10 and 13 and that didn't work either.

Comment: You'd overwrite `dl` with the 2nd `mov`... but if `dl` isn't the source register for `writechar`, it wouldn't matter anyway.